# Angular 11 : how to force function X to be execute instead of function Y at resolve ()?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

table Angular and i have list of users in a table that i want to change the type of users by click on button that execute another function ,and the problem the first function is declare at resolve () in the service.ts :

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        Promise.all([
            this.getProducts() //this is the function that bring all the users 
        ]).then(
            () => {
                resolve(this.products);
            },
            reject
        );
    });
}
```

And this is the function that i want to execute, this is service.ts

```
   getEmploye(): Promise<any>
   {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           {
               this.get7( ) 
                   .subscribe((response: any) => {
                       this.product = response;
                       resolve(response);
                       console.log(response)
                   }, reject);
           }
       });
   }
```

and i call her at the component.ts :

```
routs(){

this.router.navigate(['/apps/e-commerce/products']);
this._ecommerceProductsService.getEmploye();
```

}
and the HTML

```
   <button mat-raised-button 
        (click)="routs()" >
        <mat-icon>event</mat-icon>
        <span>Tous les clients </span>
    </button>
```

i get the data but i dont know how to put it instead of the old data:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular resolving is used for run fetch or other method automatically before routing. If you want to run getEmployee function before getProducts, you need to define getProducts directly in service and call this manually on ngOninit or whatever